# PHP gerar Pop-Up de confirmação

Tags: php, html

Tenho um código php que faz inserções no banco de dados, dados estes que vieram através de formulários, como é possível retornar uma mensagem através de um pop-up para o usuário informando-lhe se houve sucesso ou não seu cadastro/consulta? e sem haver um redirecionamento na tela?

Comment: Acho mais que falta clareza do que a pergunta seja ampla demais. Seja como for, ela depende de edições do autor, complementando o conteúdo, para que possa ser reaberta.

Comment: PHP, quando usado para exibir páginas web, não faz popup, pois é executado no servidor e não no cliente. Teria que acrescentar código em JS para isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando AJAX de maneira simples.

Considerando o seguinte formulário:

```
<form id="form-register">
    <label for="inp-nome">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" id="inp-nome" />

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Tratamos o seu evento de submit (envio) com o seguinte código JQuery:

```
$('#form-register').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var nome = $('#inp-nome').val();
    var postForm = {
        'nome': nome
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // Usa o método POST
        url: 'pagina.php', // Página que será enviada o formulário
        data: postForm, // Conteúdo do envio
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == 'sucesso') {
                alert('Foo');
            } else {
                alert('Bar');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Aqui o código PHP que fará a inserção no banco:

```
<?php
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

    // Código de tratamentos/inserções no banco aqui


    // Caso tenha inserido com sucesso
    echo "sucesso";
    // Caso contrário
    echo "falha";
?>
```

Vale notar que o que você procura mesmo é a parte do AJAX no código javascript, você pode tratar de que modo a informação será retornada de outras maneiras (utilizando a função `.html()` por exemplo).